# Changing UITableViewCell after UITextView becomes unhidden

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently, I have a UITableViewCell with a height of 406. However, I'd like the cell to expand to a height of 473 after a button is pressed. I have a hidden UITextView inside the cell and by pressing the button, the user is making the text view visible but the cell isn't getting larger.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
@IBAction func descAndText(sender: AnyObject) {

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showDesc")
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
}


func showDesc() {

    if descriptionText.hidden == true {
        hello.theTableView.rowHeight = 473
        descriptionText.hidden = false
    } else {
        descriptionText.hidden = true
        hello.theTableView.rowHeight = 406
    }

}
```

Comment: Abbreviating things decreases readability without actually decreasing the time it takes to write code (code complete means you type 2-3 letters than press tab no matter how long the word is).

Comment: Could you show some UITableView related code?

Comment: This code is done within my custom TableViewCell class. Does that change things?

Answer (score 0):

You should store information about state of cell in other place. Currently you are storing it in UILabel instance - that means it persists this information until UITableView's reload method is called, because it rebuilds every reusable cell.

I would suggest to story expand information for each cell in NSMutableArray instance and check is cell expanded or not in UITableView's data source method to give right height of cells.